# Notepad++ User Defined Language as default

Tags: notepad++

Is there any way that when I create a new tab in notepad(cntr + N) to make it open with my user defined language?
I need that because i use snippets and when I double click on someone it's opening it in a new window with no highlighting which drives me crazy.

The only solution I found for now is to change the lang file of let's say C++ and make it as default language, but there should be another way.

Comment: In SynWrite app you may set option "New document lexer", for any lexer, even user.

Answer (score 1):

You can open these documents highlighted if you change the Notepad++ properties for the user defined language.

1. Open the userDefineLang.xml (usually in "C:\Users\yourUsername\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++")
2. You have to change the second line(in my case it was the second line). The line should look like this:

   ```
   <UserLang name="Your userdefined language name" ext="your defined endings" udlVersion="2.1">
   ```
3. Add the ending of the documents you want to open highlighted with your user defined language to the "extensions of your user language".
   Now you can open documents of this type with your user defined language as default.

For Example: 

Open srf documents with the user defined language "PowerBuilder"

```
     <UserLang name="PowerBuilder" ext="srw sru srs srm" udlVersion="2.1">
```

just add the ending srf.

```
     <UserLang name="PowerBuilder" ext="srw sru srs srm srf" udlVersion="2.1">
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if you are overriding a language. For example, I created a new custom language called "my php" and set the extension to ".php" but when I create a new document and save it as <whatever>.php, the highlighting syntax changes to lang "PHP" not "my_php"...   I can however change it easily from the language menu, but I would rather it use "my php" by default...

Comment: It's 2022 and there is still no way to simply set a default user language without requiring files be saved with a specific extension??  I'm using NPP to do complex spreadsheet formulas, so I don't have them as files (not do I want to).  I just want to paste my formula in, and have it instantly highlighted so I can clean it up further as needed.  Is there really no way to just set my custom user language as the default for everything??